# Google Maps 5.1.0 crashes often. Any solution?

Tags: google-maps, crashes, system-freeze

Ever since upgrading to Google Maps 5.1.0 on my Droid X, I have often had Google Maps bog down and freeze to the point of completely crashing the phone.  Anyone else seeing this crash?  Anyone find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to Google Maps 5.2.1, released today.

Comment: I did, will report if the problem goes away.

Comment: 5.2.1 is out, updated my answer :P

Answer (score 3):

You can usually uninstall updates from the app's page in the market. However, previous updates to Google Maps had similar problems for users that never turned their phones off. Try just restarting your phone.

Comment: It's worth a shot, I suppose, but I'm seeing crashes from Maps and I've restarted my phone at least once in the interim. (Maps used to be one of the most stable apps.) I'll try another restart.

Comment: I restart it pretty regularly, because Google Maps freezes/crashes the entire phone, and therefore I have to.  Uninstalling updates is a good suggestion though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to go to `Settings` -> `Applications` -> `Manage applications` -> `All` (tab at top) -> `Maps` -> `Clear data` and/or `Clear cache`.

If somehow something is corrupted in there, this will more-or-less reset things as if Google Maps was just installed but was never used.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem and I did this, but it didn't solve the problem.